# What is difference between idealwidth and width parameter in frames in swiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

How is idealwidth different from normal width in swiftUI frames?

Answer (score 12):

Width and height are fixed values that define the dimensions of a frame. If you wrote something like this...

```
    Rectangle()
        .foregroundColor(.blue)
        .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
```

...you would have a 200x200 blue square, regardless of whether or not it fits in the parent view.

However, the *ideal* size isn't fixed. Writing something like this...

```
    Rectangle()
        .foregroundColor(.blue)
        .frame(idealWidth: 200, idealHeight: 200)
```

...would completely fill an empty view. That's because the ideal size is more of a gentle proposal that is outweighed in favor of the size proposed by the parent. For many predefined Views the ideal dimensions define how much space the View needs to be understood. For `Text()` the ideal width is the length of the string and the ideal height is the line's height.

Looking back at our ideal sized rectangle, applying `.fixedSize()` like so...

```
Rectangle()
    .foregroundColor(.blue)
    .frame(idealWidth: 200, idealHeight: 200)
    .fixedSize()
```

...would force the ideal size and create a 200x200 blue square. If you added that modifier to `Text()` you'd see it take on its ideal size as well, which in many cases would be a string so wide that it runs beyond its parent frame.

You can go further with the `.fixedSize()` modifier by defining which axises the view is defined on.

```
Rectangle()
    .foregroundColor(.blue)
    .frame(idealWidth: 200, idealHeight: 200)
    .fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: false)
```

In the above example, our Rectangle is fixed to its ideal width but can grow vertically to fill its parent. This can be useful for something like a custom button, where you might sometimes want to confine its height but allow it to stretch to fill its parent view.

You can learn a lot more from [this article](https://sarunw.com/posts/swiftui-fixedsize/#what-is-an-ideal-size) as well as [this one](https://swiftwithmajid.com/2020/04/29/the-magic-of-fixed-size-modifier-in-swiftui/). Apple also explores the ideal size a little in their discussion of the `.fixedSize()` modifier [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/fixedsize()).